# How to export Codesandbox project?

Tags: codesandbox

I can't seem to figure out why I can't download the project from Codesandbox. When I click on my project, I am redirected to this screen. Here I am working on my project but I don't see an option to export or download the project files. I have looked on the internet and most of the articles and videos have a burger menu at the top left corner but I don't have any burger menu as you can see in the picture below. Is it because I am using a cloud template instead of a static one?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer was written by the user `@hankei6km` at github in reply to my question.

The Cloud Sandbox UI seems to have changed.
I don't even know how to download files with the current UI.

However, I was able to download the files individually(not a archived .zip file) [by connecting with VSCode](https://codesandbox.io/docs/learn/repositories/editors#open-your-branch-in-vs-code).

At the time of writing this, it seems that VSCode is unable to connect to Cloud Sandbox.
(Probably a temporary failure, I was usually able to connect with VSCode)
[Codesandbox Repositories](https://codesandbox.io/docs/learn/repositories/overview) is still accessible from VSCode.

Repository opened in CodeSandbox UI
[image]
Connect to the above repository from VSCode and display "Download..." menu
[image]

Answer (score 1):

After forking a sandbox we can download the whole project by hovering over main menu at top left and click download sandbox :

[image: sandbox-download]

Answer (score 1):

Save your sandbox and Go to your 'Dashboard'.
[Go to Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pglnI.png)

Then click on the menu for the particular sandbox that you would like to export and click on 'Export Sandbox'.

[Export sandbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vmbd.png)

This seemed to work for me. Trying to download from within the sandbox itself downloaded an empty folder or a zipped folder that would display an error message when trying to extract. Downloading single files from within the sandbox left menu seems to work. Downloading folders does not.

Using Chrome on Windows 11.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me.  However, for me there was one slight difference: For me the sandbox menu on the dashboard had a "Download zip" option, I didn't see an "Export sandbox" option.  That "Download zip" option from the dashboard worked for me whereas when I tried to download using the other instructions I ended up with an empty zip file (just as Omar says).

Answer (score 0):

One way is to connect with VsCode and download each file one by one(top answer).

Another way is to connect codesandbox to a Github repo, commit & push, download zip from Github and then delete the repo (if not needed).
Note that the repo you create must be public if you don't have a premium sandbox.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I got the code from codesandbox by going to the GitHub icon on the left side and exporting it to my GitHub account as a repository.

[codesnadbox GitHub link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSPD6.png)

And then you can type the repository name, then click "Create repository", and it will create a repository in your GitHub account. You can go to your GitHub account and check it.

Answer (score 0):

I can see `export to zip`. Maybe the site has updated?

[image]